# Displaying Open or Closed Status based on Time and Day 2

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask for help with the following code. The purpose is to be open Monday to Friday during certain hours, closed on Saturday and Sunday. My problem is that this code doesn't work, it always prints "closed". I tried it yesterday and it still says "closed" during opening hours. What is wrong with this code, can someone fix it?

```js
var a = document.getElementById("hoursofoperation");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var weekdays = [
  ["Sunday"] // close
  ["Monday", 8.30, 21.30],
  ["Tuesday", 6.00, 11.30],
  ["Wednesday", 8.30, 12.00],
  ["Thursday", 8.30, 12.00],
  ["Friday", 8.30, 12.30],
  ["Saturday"] // close
];
var day = weekdays[n];

if (now > day[2] && now < day[3] || now > day[4] && now < day[5]) {
  a.innerHTML = "We are Open now now.";
} else {
  a.innerHTML = "We are Closed, kar.";
}
```

```html
<span id="hoursofoperation"></span>
```

Comment: `day[4]` and `day[5]` never exist...

Comment: Ok, but if I rewrote day[3] and day[4] it's still no good, the "open" text doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (n > 0 && n < 6 && now > day[1] && now < day[2]) {
  a.innerHTML = "We are Open now now.";
} else {
  a.innerHTML = "We are Closed, kar.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is hard. You can try this

```
var a = document.getElementById("hoursofoperation");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var now = d.getHours() + "." + d.getMinutes();
var weekdays = {
    0: null,//Sunday
    1: [8.30, 21.30],
    2: [6.00, 11.30],
    3: [8.30, 12.00],
    4: [8.30, 12.00],
    5: [8.30, 12.30],
    6: null //Saturday

}
var dayWorkingHours = weekdays[n];//Today working hours. if null we are close


if (dayWorkingHours && (now > dayWorkingHours[0] && now < dayWorkingHours[1])) {
    a.innerHTML = "We are Open now now.";
} else {
     a.innerHTML = "We are Closed, kar.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
var a = document.getElementById("hoursofoperation");
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var schedule = [{
    "day": "Sunday",
    "open": "12:00:00",
    "close": "12:00:00"
  }, // close
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "open": "8:30:00",
    "close": "21:30:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "open": "6:00:00",
    "close": "11:30:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "open": "8:30:00",
    "close": "12:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Thursday",
    "open": "8:30:00",
    "close": "12:00:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Friday",
    "open": "8:30:00",
    "close": "12:30:00"
  },
  {
    "day": "Saturday",
    "open": "12:00:00",
    "close": "12:00:00"
  } // close
];
var day = schedule[n];

if ( Date.parse( d ) > Date.parse( d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + day.open ) && Date.parse( d ) < Date.parse( d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getDate() + '-' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + day.close ) ) {
  console.log( 'we are open' );
  a.innerHTML = "We are Open now.";
}
else { 
  console.log( 'we are closed' );
  a.innerHTML = "We are Closed, kar.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it... Here's how I do it: paste the code into the html page, go and view it in a browser. Then all the code works fine. Then (glad it's good) I go back to my html page and rewrite the time at today's date. My analysis. Again I refresh f5 the browser and regardless of whether I set it to open or closed, only closed appears. What am I doing wrong? I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm in CES time zone.

Comment: Yes time zone can affect it. Yet I do not understand what you mean by you rewrite the time at today’s date. Are you setting the schedule in html?